# How to adjust panel width based on another component in wicket

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, wicket

I'm developing a wicket application and want to create a panel which need adjust the width based on another element.

The markup looks like:

```
<div wicket:id="lazyPanel" style="float: left;"></div>
<div wicket:id="widthSpan" style="float: right; width: 30%;"></div>
```

and the related java code is:

```
final WebMarkupContainer widthSpan = new WebMarkupContainer("widthSpan");
add(widthSpan);
add(new AjaxLazyLoadPanel("lazyPanel") {
     public Component getLazyLoadComponent(String markupId) {
          // calculate the width based on widthSpan
          int width = 1000 - widthOf(sidebar);
          return new MyPanel(markupId, width);
     }
});
```

I know I can use some javascript to get the width of sidebar, but how can I send it back to wicket?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a solution. Add a AjaxBehavior to widthSpan, like:

```
widthSpan.add(new AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior() {
     @Override
     protected CharSequence getCallbackScript() {
         return generateCallbackScript("wicketAjaxGet('" + getCallbackUrl() + 
                      "&ExpectedWidth=' + expectedWidth");
     }

     @Override
     public void renderHead(Component component, IHeaderResponse response) {
         super.renderHead(component, response);
         StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
         sb.append("var expectedWidth = $('#")
           .append(getComponent().getMarkupId())
           .append("').width();");
         sb.append(getCallbackScript());
         response.renderOnDomReadyScript(sb.toString());
     }

     @Override
     protected void respond(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
         int width = RequestCycle.get().getRequest().getQueryParameters()
              .getParameterValue("ExpectedWidth").toInt(280);
         Component lazy = createComponent("lazyPanel", 1000 - width);
         target.add(lazy);
     }
 };
```

Here, we use a behavior to add a query parameter ExpectedWidth and which will be retrieved from a jquery script, and in respond function, we create and add the actual panel.